# エラーがでます　incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and Windows-31J

Tags: ruby-on-rails

(Devise → Sorceryに変更中分からなくなったため）rubyをアンインストールし再インストールしました。>rails new の後、>rails s で以下のエラーがでます。

C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/path.rb:100:in `start_with?': incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and Windows-31J (Encoding::CompatibilityError)

少し調べてみたのですがよくわかりません。宜しくお願いします。
 　(Windows10 home/  Ruby 2.4.4 / Rails 5.2.0)

Comment: 解決した場合は自己回答を行い後日承認してください

Answer (score 0, accepted):

解決しました。 (Gemfileの表示は gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0'でしたが、>gem listで確認後、>gem uninstall bootsnap --version 1.3.0, でアンインストール。 [/config/boot.rb] で１行コメントアウトしました。# require 'bootsnap/setup')(https://qiita.com/Daniel_Nakano/items/aadeaa7ae4e227b73878）　                     --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

追記
その後、上記の方法ではエラーが出るようになりました。
scaffold後、何もしないままだったのですが、エラーが出てアプリを削除しました。再度アプリを同じ様に作成しようとしましたが、bootsnap --version 1.3.0削除後、以下のエラーが出ます。

```
Could not find bootsnap-1.3.0 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

そのため、Railsのバージョンを指定してインストールし、Ruby2.4.4 / Rails5.1.6 で、gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0' をインストールして今の時点で使用中です。
(短期間でバージョンが上がり、仕様も変わるのでしょうか?　当方の何か誤操作かもしれません‐‐。)